# Using std.algorithm.map with member functions in D2

Tags: dictionary, range, d, phobos

I have:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();

foreach (i; 0..10)
{
  Bar bar = foo.getBar(i);
  ...
}
```

I want to be able to instead say (equivalently):

```
foreach (bar; foo.getAllBars())
{
  ...
}
```

How do I go about implementing `getAllBars()`?

I figured something like this:

```
class Foo
{
  auto getAllBars()
  {
    return map!(getBar)(iota(10));
  }
}
```

But you can't do that of course because `getBar` depends on the `this` parameter, which will go out of scope. The same applies if you try to create a local `function` or `delegate`. I also considered creating a function object with `opCall`, but you can't use those with `map` (can you?).

Some requirements:

- The returned range must be lazy (so no copying it into an array first)
- Assume that `getBar` is the only way to get at the data.
- I want the map to be encapsulated by the class (i.e. no moving the map to the call site).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std.algorithm.map` works via a template alias parameter, and binding is at compile time.  Walter Bright (the D language designer) hasn't been clear yet on the semantics of template alias parameters in these situations, though what you're trying to do seems to *somehow* work in practice.  Clarifying this is a todo (I think).  Perhaps you would be better off asking this on the digitalmars.d newsgroup, as this would get Walter's attention and encourage him to clarify the semantics.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean be "what you're trying to do seems to somehow work in practice." -- it certainly doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Peter:  I'm as confused as you about what works and what doesn't.  All I'm saying is that in some cases delegates, etc. work in practice even though I have no idea how.  This really needs to be clarified and needs to be a bug report.  There is simply no good answer to it right now other than possibly in Walter's head.