# tasks from member functions using std.parallelism in D

Tags: d, parallel-processing

I would like to create a task that executes a member function of a struct or class:

```
import std.parallelism, std.stdio;

struct S {
    void foo() {
        writeln("S.foo()");
    }
}

void main() {
    S s;
    auto pool = new TaskPool();
    auto t = task!(s.foo)(); // error
    pool.put(t);
    pool.finish();
}
```

How can I achieve this? I also tried using delegates to no avail.

---

**edit:** I found a potentially related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848173/using-std-algorithm-map-with-member-functions-in-d2).

Comment: and if you use [scopedTask](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_parallelism.html#scopedTask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import std.parallelism, std.stdio;

struct S {
    void foo() {
        writeln("S.foo()");
    }
}

void main() {
    S s;
    auto pool = new TaskPool();
    auto t = task(&s.foo); // Constructor taking a runtime function pointer, delegate or callable (opCall).
    pool.put(t);
    pool.finish();
}
```

Output:

```
S.foo()
```

You can use `scopedTask` as well, but then you have to wait until the task has finished before returning. `TaskPool.finish` does not wait.